# BigQuery cluster usage: byes billed not clear

Tags: google-bigquery, billing

I have a bigquery table, clustered by a "company_id" field.
The total size of the table is 1.18GB

When I execute the following query:
SELECT * FROM `myproject.mydataset.Animals` where company_id='00100' LIMIT 100

I expect not only a faster execution, since I'm using the clustered field, but also a reduction in the costs.
When looking at the Job information, after the query execution, I got this:

Duration         0.6 sec
Bytes processed  1.16 GB
Bytes billed     1.16 GB
Job priority     INTERACTIVE

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2lbN2.png)

That is to say, the whole content of the table has been processed an billed.
Why?

Comment: Hey Mauro, can you show the output of the following: `SELECT SUM(1) as all_rows, SUM(CASE WHEN company_id='00100' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as target_rows FROM myproject.mydataset.Animals`

Comment: Hi! The result is Row: 1, All rows: 35100037, Bytes processed 259 B, Bytes billed: 10 MB

Comment: If I change the condition for the company_id field from 00100 to 00000 (which gets back some rows), the result would be: Rows: 1, All rows: 35100037, Target rows: 14, Bytes processed: 259 B, Bytes billed: 10 MB

Comment: What is the value of target_rows for the query in my last comment? If company_id='00100' is true for most rows of your table I think it makes sense that the amount of bytes processed should be close to the table size. 

One other thing to consider from the [BQ docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/clustered-tables):   "You might not see a significant difference in query performance between a clustered and unclustered table if the table or partition is under 1 GB."

Comment: The value of target_rows for the query of your comment is null, since the query returns 0 rows.

Comment: I have already bumped into the doc ""You might not see a significant difference in query performance between a clustered and unclustered table if the table or partition is under 1 GB." but my table is larger than 1GB

Comment: If `target_rows` is 0 then your partition is under 1 gb, no?

Comment: well, no! It means that the filtering conditions simply return 0 records. BUT if i set a filtering condition returning many records, then the result would be: Rows: 1, All rows: 35100037, Target rows: 14, Bytes processed: 259 B, Bytes billed: 10 MB

Comment: If bytes billed = 10mb doesn't that show that Bigquery is in fact not scanning your entire 1.18gb table and just looking at the partition with 14 rows?

Comment: Well, I would not say that: bytes billed are proportional to the total number of rows and of the number of fields specified in the SELECT. You suggested to use the following query: SELECT SUM(1) as all_rows, SUM(CASE WHEN company_id='00100' THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) as target_rows FROM myproject.mydataset.Animals.      ...which does not include in the SELECT all fields. In case of all fields I would get 1.18gb...